# Error while setting up Tezos sandbox - RPC request failed

Tags: rpc, sandbox

[image]

1) OS - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
2) Docker container is up and running
3) The following command fails

```
tezos-client -A localhost -P 20000 bootstrapped.
```

The error messages is

```
Rpc request failed:
 - meth: GET
 - uri : https://localhost:20000/monitor/bootstrapped
 - error: Unable to connect to the node: "End_of_file"
```

Comment: How did you start the sandbox? which command?

Comment: From Riot it seems you are running the setup  from https://assets.tqtezos.com/setup/2-sandbox
(I just tried, it works for me)


You can get the node logs with:
`docker exec my-sandbox cat /tmp/mini-box/node-N000/node-output.log`

Or the logs of the baker at: `docker exec my-sandbox cat /tmp/mini-box/output/baker-bootacc-0-for-N000/stderr.log`

Comment: Also which version of `docker` are you using?
(since gitlab have upgraded their docker infrastructure, we've seen some problems around)

Comment: It seems that your client is configured to use HTTPS while the sandbox is listening on HTTP.